# Rail 4 unable to load Model in script in lib folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to create some scripts in lib folder which should insert/update data in my db. I would like to use my models but they are not loaded when I try to use them. These scripts are not related to the application, they are cronjobs. What is the best behavior to implement this logic? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to run cron jobs, you might want to take a look at [Delayed Job gem](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) and put your classes in `app/jobs`.

Comment: I was thinking about Capistrano. If I use it I can easily fix my issue with the following code 

every :friday, :at => "4am" do
  runner "Model.method"
end but I am interested in using model in the lib too

Comment: Are you in rails 3 or 4 ?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a rake task under lib/tasks/my_db_task.rake
When defining the rake task, make sure it depends on the "environment" one, which will load all the required dependencies you need to interact with your models (and all other classes, libraries usually available within your rails app)

```
desc "insert stuff in my db"
task populate_db: :environment do
    10.times { User.create! name: "bob"}
end
```

And in you cron use something like the following (of course adapt to your environment):

```
* * * * * cd $RAILS_APP && RAILS_ENV=production /usr/local/bin/rake populate_db
```